# use of tag rel=canonical for duplicate contents

Tags: seo, canonical-link, duplicate-content

On my website, a product page can be reached in different ways, eg:

```
www.example.com/gallery/details/product_1/category_1
www.example.com/gallery/details/product_1/category_2
www.example.com/gallery/details/product_1/category_3
```

As I guess these urls are duplicate content since they all show the same product page, how should I define a canonical URL to prevent google from penalizing the duplicate content?

Best way should probably be:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.example.com/gallery/details/product_1">
```

But users cannot follow this link as products are filtered by categories and one product may have several categories.
Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Pick a default category that should be the one found in the search results. This *probably* should be the most popular (i.e. most searched for) category.
2. Make it so the URLs with no category *works*. It does not have to be found via your website (i.e. a category page or search functionality). It just has to be available.

Comment: Thanks John, I was thinking just the second option, this way the canonical url makes sense. The downside is on the product page I will have next/previous links showing all the products regardless of category.